# ' I'm curious to see...'

Tags: vocabulary

To be curious= [**To be eager to know or learn something**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curious).

What does it mean then to say:'I'm curious to see something' ?

Comment: It means ***Seeing it would satisfy my curiosity.***

Answer (score 1):

(in proper context)

> It would be *interesting* for me to see (it with my own eyes).